# Why is TaskCanceledException not being caught but other exceptions are?

Tags: c#, async-await, plugins

I am using Prise Plugin Framework and MailKit SMTP Client.

During the ConnectAsync call, if the async call timeouts, it will throw a TaskCanceledException. This will be caught in the caller and after logging it will be thrown down the call stack. But this will not be caught after the Execute method in the Prise plugin and the app will crash - other exceptions are being caught fine and don't crash the app.

```
try
{
    await _smtpClient.ConnectAsync(sendEmail.Host, sendEmail.Port);
    // other code
}
catch
{
    // logging
    throw;
}
```

This code is being called by the plugin with `return await service.ExecuteAsync(parameters, context);`

I'm expecting this to throw the exception to its parent but it doesn't happen.

EDIT: I will add the plugin class and how it is used:

```
[Plugin(PluginType = typeof(IPlugin))]
[PluginDescription(Description = "Email plugin.")]
public class Email : BasePlugin<EmailInputModel>
{
    [field: PluginService(ProvidedBy = ProvidedBy.Host, ServiceType = typeof(IServiceProvider))]
    private IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    [PluginActivated]
    public void OnActivated()
    {
        InitializeServices(ServiceProvider);
    }

    protected override async Task<PluginExecutionResult> ExecutePluginAsync(
        EmailInputModel parameters,
        PluginExecutionContext context,
        IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        IEmailPluginService service = provider.GetRequiredService<IEmailPluginService>();
        return await service.ExecuteAsync(parameters, context);
    }
}

// method that calls the plugin execute method:
public async Task<PluginExecutionResult> ExecuteAsync(string parameters, PluginExecutionContext context)
{
    try
    {
        var pluginParameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TInput>(parameters);

        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        return await ExecutePluginAsync(pluginParameters, context, scope.ServiceProvider);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // this is where I expect the exception to be caught, but somehow it isn't
        throw;
    }
}
```

EDIT2: I managed to fix this by catching the exception `OperationCanceledException` after it timeouts during connect and handling it to throw a custom exception in the `catch` block.

Comment: There is obviously not enough information here. The shown code should work as expected (have you tried to debug it), this requires a [mre]. Possibly you should address the question to the plugin authors first, may be they are ignoring the exception for some reason.

Comment: What is the goal here: Find out what to complain about to the plugin authors? How to avoid crashing? Both? Something else, entirely?

Comment: And [no repro](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AKgBZgCmAhgCYCWUA5gNzpa5ICsza6wYAnugDe6bKOwA3CmGwBjYAGdsAXmxQyAd2wBhClBlkANgYrAaAeyiEzAazJQAymYhh9ACgCUXMbIX4deww8vMTgATlwANnwAMTAzAFt/fQMyKlc5eSIbO08RMQB6fOwzYGIyaRkzKjJ0AF90GRMZYmxXAFEAD30AB1MLbDJ3ITzRPFDXACJAHg3AEH3sCewAagHctG9SuPUuWqA===)

Comment: It's absolutely out of sight that there is something wrong with the logging part?

Comment: @GuruStron yes, during debugging it will just exit the current thread, it will not continue to bubble up.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods, I wish to know if somehow that exception is not being propagated, perhaps someone used prise before and encountered such an issue

Comment: @DanS according to everything I know - it should be propagated (unless there is some nasty little bug in the version of runtime you are using), there are uncatchable exceptions in .NET, but I have never heard of unpropagatable.

Comment: Without seeing how you are using the plugin how can we help

Comment: @Charlieface I added some code that hopefully it is what you asked

Comment: `async void` causes unpropagatable exceptions. So do discarded tasks if `ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions` is set (or if op is still on - shudder - .NET 4.0). I don't see any evidence of either in the posted code, though.

Comment: @StephenCleary if it _was_ `async void` then _no_ Exception would propagate, right? Because OP said, other Exception types do propagate just fine.

Comment: @StephenCleary this is on .NET 6 and ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions is not used

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods: yes, but there's definitely something incorrectly or incompletely stated.

Comment: @DanS: I suspect some code somewhere is catching and ignoring `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: Do you perhaps have Visual Studio setup to break on all exceptions? ("Common Language Runtime Exceptions" is checked in the Exception Settings) If so, it will break even when the exception is handled later.

Comment: @GabrielLuci yes, I have that checkbox enabled but sadly it won't break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by catching the exception `OperationCanceledException` after it timeouts during connect and handling it to throw a custom exception in the `catch` block.

Comment: @Sampath in our case, the reason was that in case an incorect supplied encryption parameter for the `ConnectAsync` method was supplied - i.e. sending a `SecureOptions.Tls` to a server that hasn't got TLS enabled.